# Application Error, heroku hosting, backend App

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku

Guys i'm trying to make a hosting for my backend app, and this is the second time i do it, the problem is that, i have this error

[image]

And, i tried to log my app so i can see where is the error, and this appears

```
2021-03-21T18:22:21.067459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2021-03-21T18:22:25.290401+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:25.290415+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-21T18:22:25.290416+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon index.js
2021-03-21T18:22:25.290416+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:25.316554+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2021-03-21T18:22:25.362375+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-21T18:22:25.363310+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-03-21T18:22:25.364814+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-03-21T18:22:25.365654+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:22:25.388201+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `nodemon index.js`
2021-03-21T18:22:25.388571+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:22:25.389012+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-21T18:22:25.389281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
server@1.0.0 start script.
2021-03-21T18:22:25.389521+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-21T18:22:25.400950+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:25.401357+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-21T18:22:25.401620+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-21T18_22_25_390Z-debug.log
2021-03-21T18:22:25.500796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
status 1
2021-03-21T18:22:25.573335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-21T18:22:25.576936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-21T18:22:28.365986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2021-03-21T18:22:30.896431+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:30.896468+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-21T18:22:30.896468+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon index.js
2021-03-21T18:22:30.896468+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:30.907038+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2021-03-21T18:22:30.919190+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-21T18:22:30.919692+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-03-21T18:22:30.919949+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-03-21T18:22:30.920239+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `nodemon index.js`
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927284+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927492+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
server@1.0.0 start script.
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927851+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-21T18:22:30.963521+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:30.963855+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-21T18:22:30.964051+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-21T18_22_30_928Z-debug.log
2021-03-21T18:22:31.015557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
status 1
2021-03-21T18:22:31.101810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-21T18:22:44.381282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com
request_id=836abccf-8d2c-432d-a50f-53810887e9ad fwd="177.254.11.56"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-21T18:22:48.388632+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 d
PS C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Portafolio\Fullstack Projects\Daily App - MERN\server> heroku restartRestarting dynos on ⬢ daily-mern... done
PS C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Portafolio\Fullstack Projects\Daily App - MERN\server> heroku logs --tail --app daily-mern
2021-03-21T18:15:05.905941+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user diegodarkusgamer24@gmail.com
2021-03-21T18:15:05.905941+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user diegodarkusgamer24@gmail.com
2021-03-21T18:15:06.053078+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user diegodarkusgamer24@gmail.com
2021-03-21T18:15:06.053078+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user diegodarkusgamer24@gmail.com
2021-03-21T18:21:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user diegodarkusgamer24@gmail.com
2021-03-21T18:22:16.855697+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 81dac1f3 by user diegodarkusgamer24@gmail.com
2021-03-21T18:22:16.855697+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user diegodarkusgamer24@gmail.com
2021-03-21T18:22:16.875164+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user diegodarkusgamer24@gmail.com
2021-03-21T18:22:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-21T18:22:21.067459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2021-03-21T18:22:25.290401+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:25.290415+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-21T18:22:25.290416+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon index.js
2021-03-21T18:22:25.290416+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:25.316554+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2021-03-21T18:22:25.362375+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-21T18:22:25.363310+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-03-21T18:22:25.364814+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-03-21T18:22:25.365654+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:22:25.388201+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `nodemon index.js`
2021-03-21T18:22:25.388571+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:22:25.389012+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-21T18:22:25.389281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
server@1.0.0 start script.
2021-03-21T18:22:25.389521+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-21T18:22:25.400950+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:25.401357+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-21T18:22:25.401620+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-21T18_22_25_390Z-debug.log
2021-03-21T18:22:25.500796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
status 1
2021-03-21T18:22:25.573335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-21T18:22:25.576936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-21T18:22:28.365986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2021-03-21T18:22:30.896431+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:30.896468+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-21T18:22:30.896468+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon index.js
2021-03-21T18:22:30.896468+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:30.907038+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2021-03-21T18:22:30.919190+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-21T18:22:30.919692+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-03-21T18:22:30.919949+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-03-21T18:22:30.920239+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `nodemon index.js`
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927284+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927492+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
server@1.0.0 start script.
2021-03-21T18:22:30.927851+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-21T18:22:30.963521+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:22:30.963855+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-21T18:22:30.964051+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-21T18_22_30_928Z-debug.log
2021-03-21T18:22:31.015557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
status 1
2021-03-21T18:22:31.101810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-21T18:22:44.381282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com
request_id=836abccf-8d2c-432d-a50f-53810887e9ad fwd="177.254.11.56"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-21T18:22:48.388632+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com request_id=4872869b-653b-411c-8041-6c74f2c933d1 fwd="177.254.11.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-21T18:23:28.033455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com
request_id=938148d2-e2b9-44ec-b0e3-7c36a15c30bb fwd="177.254.11.56"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-21T18:23:32.633910+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com request_id=12ce541f-e48b-43f0-895f-4987388d0918 fwd="177.254.11.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-21T18:33:27.499912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-21T18:33:30.454323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2021-03-21T18:33:33.252960+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:33:33.252982+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-21T18:33:33.252982+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon index.js
2021-03-21T18:33:33.252983+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:33:33.265627+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2021-03-21T18:33:33.280021+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-21T18:33:33.280574+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-03-21T18:33:33.280907+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-03-21T18:33:33.281222+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:33:33.289740+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `nodemon index.js`
2021-03-21T18:33:33.290008+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-03-21T18:33:33.290328+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-21T18:33:33.290552+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
server@1.0.0 start script.
2021-03-21T18:33:33.290851+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-21T18:33:33.303493+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-21T18:33:33.304537+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-21T18:33:33.304746+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-21T18_33_33_292Z-debug.log
2021-03-21T18:33:33.372157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
status 1
2021-03-21T18:33:33.483971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-21T18:35:58.992675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com
request_id=af1f361c-1574-4a32-8f68-a7f0830c007a fwd="177.254.11.56"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-21T18:36:01.295985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com request_id=759fada6-a151-4bdd-8689-5eab38ceaf35 fwd="177.254.11.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-21T18:36:27.162149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com
request_id=a44bcfca-29b0-4264-bc39-878747caad85 fwd="177.254.11.56"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-21T18:36:30.775177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=daily-mern.herokuapp.com request_id=ea89bde9-0278-4ded-b9e9-95925bef286b fwd="177.254.11.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I don't understand anything, what is goin on? how can i fix that?

This is my index of my backend, i'm working with node, express and mongoDB

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

import rooms from "./routes/rooms.js";
import user from "./routes/user.js";
import tasks from "./routes/tasks.js";

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ limit: "20mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "20mb", extended: true }));

app.use(cors());

app.use("/rooms", rooms);

app.use("/tasks", tasks);

app.use("/user", user);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("");
});

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  dbName: "Daily-App"
});

mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server Working Succesfully");
});
```

My procfile

```
web: npm run start
```

My package json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.19"
  }
}
```

If you know what's going on, i would love to read your answer, thank your for your time comunnity !

Answer (score 1):

1. Add node version to your package.json: `"engines": { "node": "v15.10.0" }`
2. Change the "start" script from "nodemon server.js" to "node server.js". If you want to use nodemone locally, add one more script like : `"dev": "nodemon server.js"` and `use npm run dev` to start the server locally.
3. You must push your .env to your heroku server also.
   Check if you .env file is being ignored in .gitignore.

ps: package.json: I don't see "nodemon" in your "dependencies".
did you installed it? If you installed it, it should be there like : `"nodemon": "^2.0.7"`   or if you installed it with `npm i --save-dev`:  `"devDependencies": { "nodemon": "^2.0.7" }`
Wish this help you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answering me, i'll fix that using your advice, thank you again !